# Printing an array that already contains values

Tags: java, arrays

I'm experimenting with code, and I was wondering how would I go about printing an array that already contains values? If I were to add something like "The temperatures of the week are: " and then print the list out to the user.
This is my code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {



    Scanner keyboard=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("How many temperatures?");
    int size=keyboard.nextInt();
    int temp[]=new int[size];
    System.out.println("Please enter "+temp.length+" temperatures");
    double sum=0;
    for(int i=0;i<temp.length;i++){
        temp[i]=keyboard.nextInt();
        sum=sum+temp[i];
    }
    double average=sum/temp.length;
    System.out.println("The average temperature is: "+average);

    for(int i=0;i<temp.length;i++){

        if (temp[i]>average){
            System.out.println("Above average: "+temp[i]);
        }
        else if(temp[i]<average){
            System.out.println("Below average: "+temp[i]);
        }
        else if(temp[i]==average){
            System.out.println("Equal to average "+temp[i]);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: now what is the exact problem?? :)

Comment: That I didn't know how to print the array out in a manner that the individually entered values would line up next to each other

Comment: is the problem solved now as @turingcomplete answered you?? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either explicitly loop through the array, or use the Arrays.toString method.

```
int [] arr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
System.out.print("The temperatures of the week are: ");
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    System.out.print(arr[i]+" ");
System.out.println();
```

or you could

```
    System.out.println("The temperatures of the week are: " + Arrays.toString(arr));
```

You need to first import java.util.Arrays to use the Arrays class.

Comment: I didn't import the array class, I just used a for loop but it gave me the output I desired

Comment: Both will print the array, the only difference is that Arrays.toString will print the array surrounded by square brackets like [1, 2, 3, 4].